# For what value $\alpha$ is the variance of $\operatorname{Par}(\alpha)$ distribution finite?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

So I'm trying to figure out for which values of $\alpha$ the variance of the Pareto distribution is finite and to then calculate the variance for the $\alpha$ that make it finite. I'm not really sure how to approach this.

I'm aware the variance of the Pareto distribution is $\frac{\alpha}{(\alpha-1)^2(\alpha-2)}$

Naturally I would think for any values that are not $\alpha = 1$ or $\alpha = 2$, but I'm not sure if this is all there is to it, since according to my formulae sheet, $\alpha$ needs to be $>2$? Not sure why this is.

Would appreciate some help, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When $\alpha <2$, the formula you quoted for the variance yields a negative number, so the formula can't be valid in that case.

To decide conditions on $\alpha$ to make the variance finite, it's enough to find the values of $\alpha$ where the integral $E(X^2):=\int_1^\infty x^2f_\alpha(x)\,dx$ is finite. (I'm writing $f_\alpha(x)$ for the density function for the Pareto distribution with parameter $\alpha$.)